# TypeScript - Problems importing some npm packages that use declaration files (typings) from DefinitelyTyped

Tags: typescript, definitelytyped, react-modal, react-big-calendar

For some of the modules I'm importing I end up modifying their declaration files to get them working. I'm not sure if I'm going about it wrong or if there just happen to be issues with the typings for these modules.

**index.tsx**

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as moment from "moment";
import BigCalendar from "react-big-calendar";
import ReactModal from "react-modal";
```

`react` and `moment` import fine. The problems are with `react-big-calendar` and `react-modal`. This is basically the process I went through for `react-modal`:

I installed `@types/react-modal`.

**node_modules/@types/react-modal/index.d.ts (abbreviated)**

```
// Type definitions for react-modal 1.6
// Project: https://github.com/reactjs/react-modal
// Definitions by: Rajab Shakirov <https://github.com/radziksh>, Drew Noakes <https://github.com/drewnoakes>, Thomas B Homburg <https://github.com/homburg>
// Definitions: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped
// TypeScript Version: 2.3

import * as React from "react";

export as namespace ReactModal;

export = ReactModal;

declare namespace ReactModal {
    interface Props {
        ...
    }
}

declare class ReactModal extends React.Component<ReactModal.Props> {
    ...
}
```

I tried `import ReactModal from "react-modal"` which gives me `Module '...' has no default export`.

I tried `import { ReactModal } from "react-modal"` 
which gives me `Module '...' has no exported member 'ReactModal'`.

I tried `import * asReactModal from "react-modal"`  which compiles, but gives me `Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object` at run time.

Eventually I just altered the declaration file to this:

```
import * as React from "react";

export as namespace ReactModal;

declare namespace ReactModal {
    interface Props {
        ...
    }
}

export default class ReactModal extends React.Component<ReactModal.Props> {
    ...
}
```

Then I could use `import ReactModal from "react-modal"`, and it worked.

With `react-big-calendar` I just uninstalled `@types/react-big-calendar` and now have my own typings for it. Surely other people are using these declaration files for these packages without all this hassle. Any guidance would be appreciated.

**package.json**

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "@types/react": "^15.0.27",
        "@types/react-dom": "^15.5.0",
        "@types/react-modal": "^1.6.7",
        "moment": "^2.18.1",
        "react": "^15.5.4",
        "react-big-calendar": "^0.14.0",
        "react-dom": "^15.5.4",
        "react-modal": "^2.1.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.1.3",
        "babel-core": "^6.24.1",
        "babel-loader": "^7.0.0",
        "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
        "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
        "css-loader": "^0.28.4",
        "source-map-loader": "^0.2.1",
        "style-loader": "^0.18.2",
        "typescript": "^2.3.4",
        "webpack": "^2.5.0"
    }
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./Scripts/dist/",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "target": "es5",
        "jsx": "react"
    },
    "include": [
        "./Scripts/src/**/*"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Your types are not correctly installed : `npm install --save-dev @types/node` from the documentation

Comment: Thanks @OrcusZ. I've fixed that up. I take it that wasn't intended to address this particular issue?

Comment: I'm having this same issue after updating my packages.

Comment: Your edit of react-modal/index.d.ts worked for me. It seems really wrong to edit the definition down in node packages. There must be a better way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [react-modal/index.d.ts](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react-modal/index.d.ts) has a bug and you (or I) should submit a pull request. If I interpret their [react-modal-tests.tsx](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react-modal/react-modal-tests.tsx#L2) correctly, they import it with `import * as ReactModal from 'react-modal';` which compiles but doesn't run. My impression is their tests only compile.

I figured out how to get it to work without modifying the file way down in node_packages/@types.

Add these lines to the `compilerOptions` section of the tsconfig file:

    `"baseUrl": "src/types",
    "typeRoots": [ "./src/types", "./node_modules/@types" ]`

Then put your modified `react-modal/index.d.ts` in `src/types/react-modal/index.d.ts`. The typescript compiler should then find it there. I simply copied the contents of `node_modules/@types/react-modal` to `src/types/react-modal` and made your changes.

Comment: Thanks Gary. Apologies for the delay in getting back to you. I suspected there could be issues with the declarations, but I'm not familiar enough with TypeScript to conclude that myself. I doubted myself even more when I had the same issue with two separate sets of declarations. I now have my own types in with my source, and have uninstalled the npm @type packages.